# Do I need any library before adding google analytics to my website?

Tags: google-analytics

I have got the google analytics code which is written below

```
<script>
  (function(i,s,o,g,r,a,m){i['GoogleAnalyticsObject']=r;i[r]=i[r]||function(){
  (i[r].q=i[r].q||[]).push(arguments)},i[r].l=1*new Date();a=s.createElement(o),
  m=s.getElementsByTagName(o)[0];a.async=1;a.src=g;m.parentNode.insertBefore(a,m)
  })(window,document,'script','//www.google-analytics.com/analytics.js','ga');

  ga('create', 'xx-xxxxxx-x', 'auto');
  ga('send', 'pageview');

</script>
```

I searched on net a lot but could not find my answer. Do I need any library before adding this code to my web just like we add jQuery library before adding jQuery script.

Comment: No. It will pretty much load everything it needs on its own.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can just paste the code in right before the `</head>` tag

Set up the web tracking code:
https://support.google.com/analytics/answer/1008080?hl=en

Answer (score 1):

You can just add that code to your website, place it just before the `</head>` tag. No extra libraries are needed.